# sum or polynomial of a polynomial?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, algorithms, computational-complexity

I am trying to answer the following math problem but I barely understand the question.

If $P(i)$ is a polynomial of degree $d$ in $i$ then $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n p(i)$ is a polynomial of $d + 1$ in $n$. Imagine that $P(i) = 2i^3 + 4i^2 + 2$ what is $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n p(i)$

Could somebody please give me some pointers on what they want to know? Or what "tools" I can use to fix this problem? Do I need to use Newtons Binomial theorem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would help if you knew the formula for the sum of the first $n$ cubes and the sum of the first $n$ squares. Probably you have seen at least one of these already.  The Binomial Theorem can be used to show the general result about degree $d+1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\sum_{i=0}^n (2i^3 + 4i^2 + 2) = 2\left( \sum_{i=0}^n i^3 \right) + 4\left( \sum_{i=0}^n i^2 \right) + 2\left( \sum_{i=0}^n 2 \right).
$$
Therefore, it is enough to deal with each of $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n i^k$ for $k=0,1,2,3,\ldots$.  For that we need the [Bernoulli polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials) $B_n$, characterized by
$$
\int_x^{x+1} B_n(u)\,du = x^n.
$$
We have
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n i^k = \frac{B_{k+1}(i+1)-B_{k+1}(0)}{k+1}.
$$